# How do operating systems compute file size?

Tags: file-io, operating-system

If I understand correctly, most programming language which provide a library function to retrieve the size of a file use a system call. But then, what does the system do under the hood? Does it depend on the file system? Is the size information stored in some kind of a file header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is filesystem dependent, but many filesystems do it in roughly the same way: for each file, there is a block on the hard drive that stores metadata about the file, including its size.

For many of the filesystems used in Linux/UNIX, for example, this block is called an [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Note that the inode is not actually part of the file, so it's not really a header; it exists in a region of the disc that is reserved for storing metadata, not file data.

On [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), the filesystem used by Windows, file size data is stored in the master file table. This is roughly equivalent to the inode table on a Linux filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in a file's metadata, which you can retrieve with `stat` on POSIX systems. The metadata also includes, for example, when the file was last modified or accessed.

Answer (score 2):

They're stored in a structure called an Inode:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

This contains all of your file's metadata; when you modify the contents of a file (or really do anything with it), your Inode gets updated.